# Added a .6rem solid top border that activates on hover. However, it pushes the navigation down

Tags: html, css

I've created a nav menu where the menu items display a .6rem solid top border on hover.

The problem I'm having is that the on hover action pushes the menu items down.

I have tried to add a transparent border-top to the parent css but it doesn't make a difference.

```
.site-header .nav-primary {
    border-top: .6rem solid transparent;
}
.site-header .nav-primary a:hover {
    color: #000; 
    border-top: .6rem solid #bfdcee;
```

I expect that when I hover over a nav list item, the .6rem top border displays without shifting the entire primary nav down.

Answer (score -1):

Solved: So I added removed `border-top: .6rem solid transparent;` from the parent and added `margin-top: .6rem;`.

Then for the child, I subtracted the margin-top on hover `margin-top: -.6rem;`.

This seems to have done the trick.

Comment: you simply make it more complex .. the transparent border need to go to the `a` and your done